# Package X is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I'm trying to run my .net core 3.1 project in VS 2019 but I'm getting errors like a below during building.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource 4.5.0 does not support any target frameworks.    WebApi.Base C:\Users\ilyas.varol.TEST\source\repos\performancemanagementprojects\WebApi.Base\WebApi.Base.csproj

Notes:

- I made reinstalling all packages and .net core 3.1 sdk
- The same project is running in another computer

**UPDATE**

I still haven't solve my problem. Therefore I want to elaborate my question with screenshots. I hope someone can help me.

Error list
[image]

Nuget Package Manager > Consolidate

[image]

Comment: if you get these errors in DevOps NuGetCommand try changing the nuget version. For yaml: 

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>= 5.5.1'

Comment: @RussellMunro you saved my butt with this comment. Thanks!

Comment: @RussellMunro thanks for this comments. For me 5.0.10 worked properly. Today the latest version of this NuGet package is 6.0.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I clicked right click on sln and then I clicked "Clean Solution" and Rebuild Solution". Finally, My problem is solved.

Answer (score 9):

First, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

Then, delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

Rebuild the project to test again.

Comment: I tried that you said several times but I am getting the same error

Comment: close VS, then delete files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`, `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` folder, restart VS, could it help?

Comment: I deleted files you said but it didn't help me though, anyway thanks!

Comment: Does `Clear All Nuget Caches` button under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`General` help? Does a new project has the same error? If so, you have to [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS if there is a new release.

Comment: I'm so glad for your effort but I also tried this :/

Comment: also repair or reinstall?

Comment: now, I repaired VS 2019 Pro and tried you said before, but didn't work. Idk what should I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228569/discussion-between-ilyas-varol-and-perry-qian-msft).

Answer (score 2):

Following worked for me on VS 2019,

```
Tools-->Nuget Package Manager-->Package Manager Settings-->General-->Clear All NuGet Cache(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, as mentioned in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) I updated the `target framework`.

Specifically, of my class libraries (in Blazor server core 3.1).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> //remove this
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>        //add this
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

After this, you need to remove the `bin`, `obj` folder and rebuild the project.

This should get you are up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

For me 5.0.10 worked properly. Today the latest version of this NuGet package is 6.0.6 but I tried 5.0.10 and  worked properly